# Reference checkboxes within nested divs with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some checkboxes within a div that are limited by the number within `data-max-answers` (which is grabbed from Wordpress). So if that number is 2 then the user can only tick 2 of the checkboxes with the others greyed out.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to drill down through the divs to target the checkboxes, can anyone help me out?

I have a simplified version where the checkboxes are directly within the div, this works fine but can't get it to work for mine where theres nested divs - http://jsfiddle.net/pVA3d/4/.

```
<div class="question" data-max-answers="<?php echo $repeater_row['required_answers']; ?>">
    <?php $rows = $repeater_row['answer_options'];
    foreach ($rows as $row){ ?>
    <?php $Question[$counter] = $_POST['answer'.$counter]; ?>
    <div style="display:table-row;">
        <div style="display:table-cell;">
            <input style="width: 20px;" type="checkbox" name="answer<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" value="<?php echo the_sub_field('answer'); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div style="display:table-cell;">
            <p>
                <?php echo $row['answer']; ?>
            </p>
        </div>              
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.currentTarget).closest("div.question").length > 0) {
            toggleInputs($(e.currentTarget).closest("div.question")[0]);        
        }
    });
});
});

jQuery(function($) {
function toggleInputs(questionElement) {
    if ($(questionElement).data('max-answers') == undefined) {
        return true;
    } else {
        maxAnswers = parseInt($(questionElement).data('max-answers'), 10); 
        if ($(questionElement).find(":checked").length >= maxAnswers) {
            $(questionElement).find(":not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $(questionElement).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Can you point out the specific line that is giving you a problem?

Comment: @JamesMontagne In the fiddle linked in the question, all the checkboxes are within one div, whereas mine are nested. I think it has something to do with the jquery, specifically the second function block.

Comment: I used the same nested structure and your js code here and it worked fine... http://jsfiddle.net/pVA3d/5/ - perhaps you could show us your html source (not php) so we could see if there is a problem there. Also, do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference based on your code.  Have you debugged the code to find where it is going wrong?  Perhaps you could created a fiddle with the non-working code.  I tried and it works just fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/pVA3d/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing

`Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleInputs is not defined`

when I click checkboxes on your url. Is there any reason you are wrapping each individual jquery function? try putting your toggleInputs function within the same wrapper as your input click function